# how to derivate with respect to someother variable other than time?

Tags: modelica

I am just starting with modelica. I am aware that there is an inbuilt time derivative operator [der(expr)]. In case if i have to derivate with some other variable how can that be done ? for eg: if i have to derivate w.r.t a variable 'x'  how can this be formed?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you'll have to declare the derivative explicitly if you need something other than time derivatives, for example

```
y = x^2;    
der_y = 2x;
```

The variable der_y should be declared earlier in the model, as should y and x. If you would like a double derivative, say, then you could do something like

```
dder_y = 2;
```

with the variable dder_y decleared earlier, as before.

I haven't often felt the need for other derivatives than time derivatives when making Modelica models. That being said, I'm quite new to Modelica myself, so there may very well come a time when I do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding in your suggestions.

Comment: Happy to help! There might (very well) be a more elegant solution than my suggestion - please let me know if you find any somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the possibility of using the annotation `derivative=<NameOfDerivativeFunction>` to tell the tool which function to use in order to take the derivative of your function:

Example from the [Modelica Specification, chapter 12.7.1](https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec32Revision1.pdf):

```
function foo0 annotation(derivative=foo1); end foo0;
function foo1 annotation(derivative(order=2)=foo2); end foo1;
function foo2 end foo2;
```

You can find more information in chapter 12.7.1. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable input. I will try using these annotations.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to derive y over x, provided both variables are continuous, utilizes dy/dx = (dy/dt) / (dx/dt), i.e. in Modelica

`dydx = der(y)/der(x)`.

We use it e.g. for derivatives of cartesian coordinates of a curve over its arc length.

Comment: Problem appear when der(x) is equal or near zero. Do you know any method to "handle" this?

Comment: @Mimi I guess this is very case-specific. One can use a fix value of `dydx` for that case, or to add a small offset to the denominator, i.e. `der(y)/(der(x)+eps). But there are surely more possibilities.

Comment: Nice idea. I have small comment to it, eps should be somehow in "if" statement, due to situation where der(x)=-eps.

Comment: Yes. The trick with eps would work seamlessly e.g. in situations where x has some lower limit by nature. E.g. for a length.